# More control over multicollider

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

> Related: [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

Today, we had [a guy who had an issue with a naggy user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132919/178438). This sort of sparked me into coming up with a new feature-request (Can't find a dupe, surprised).

Basically, we should have more control over what does and does not appear in the multicollider. This includes:

- Muting comments and/or answers on a specific post.
- Muting comments from a specific user
- Ignoring all comments not addressed to you in a post of yours (I don't think this is that good, though--many times comments address both the OP and the other guy).
- Ignoring certain chat rooms
- The ability to make answers/comments on posts written by *others* to ping your multicollider.

Note that "Mute" could mean that it shows up in the inbox, but doesn't trigger the colorful glowing circle on the multicollider.

---

With the new "notifications" thing, there may be some scope in making certain notifications opt-in or opt-out (not all of these exist, but many would be useful in the notifications tab):

- Notification of rejected edit
- Notification of [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts
- Notification of change to favorites
- Notification of certain badges
- Notification of edits
- Notification of edits to posts you have upvoted
- Notification of edits to posts you have downvoted (yes, should be separate)
   - Notification of edits to posts you have closevoted

Comment: MUTE ALL THE USERS!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just solve the actual problem by dealing with the offending user(s)? If they're annoying one person like this, they're likely to start annoying other users as well. The solution is not for everyone to start ignoring them, it's to remove the assholes from the site or *persuade* them to change their behavior.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: This is not just related to bad users. It can be a good post, getting lots of attention, etc. For example, [Poor Ólafur get's pinged every time here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3122/revisions?page=3).Comments on popular posts as well.  But yeah, I see your point--this would be useful most for naggy users &c, and we already have flags for that.

Comment: @man sandbox is an exceptional case and even that could be dealt with by a dev in an exceptional way by stripping ownership of the post

Comment: @the you should post that as an answer, as it is the only correct answer. Treat disease, not symptoms.

Comment: Another use case which brought me here (actually, to a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298410/can-i-mute-notifications-on-a-specific-question)). I have a stupid old question that's gotten famous and I'd much rather not be informed about the upvotes it receives. It'd be good if I could mute at least upvote notifications on it. New answers or comments could still be useful to look at