# Indicate revisions in vote history

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, vote-to-close

I'm against all the "notify me when a post I downvoted is updated" requests, but I had an idea that might be useful while unobtrusive.

How about quietly showing how many revisions/edits were made between your downvote and now? It could also "clear" when you recheck the post, so they don't stay marked as "updated"

Mockup:

[image]

The % edited and revision count are just ideas to help show the *magnitude* of the change. If someone changes "Im" to "I'm" the revised post probably isn't even worth a look, so I think the % edited is a good criteria to go on. I could at a glance (and on my own time) see which of the posts I downvoted/close voted have been updated. Maybe make the (% edited) text a link to the latest revision so I can see what changed (I often do this when I forget why I closed a question. It happens.)

As a mod it'd be really nice to see when posts I've closed have been edited as well; ideally users would flag/vote to reopen a post when it's fixed, but very few people seem to flag.

This would make it easy for us to *optionally* review our downvotes/other votes without making voting a massive burden (some proposals requiring comments/notifications on posts we downvote could easily get very invasive and annoying).

Comment: Another way to do it would be to add it to the notifications tab. Of course, for some users that'll flood it, which is why [making the multicollider flexible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132922/178438) would solve this.

Answer (score 2):

To add to this proposal, to make it *much* easier to see the changes, do what is currently done in the responses > revisions category: a diff-view *at that place!*:

> [image: Responses>revisions live-diff]

As you can see in the image, the diff is shown when you click the `>` button.

So, as this is already implemented elsewhere, it should be easy to do the same on the votes tab.

---

In the votes tab *currently*, the `>` button *does exist* already:

> [image: Current 'votes' tab view]

(excuse the messy red scribbling :P)

---

So I propose:

- add the number of revision(s) *since the action occurred* (and not since last view, simply because it will be easier to implement)
- if there has been a revisions since the action, rather than showing the question on click of `>`, **show the diff**, as is done for current revisions to *own posts*!