# Add a visual cue to "votes cast" tab to indicate modification

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes

On the votes tab (specifically down-votes):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/[your-id]/[your-name]?tab=votes&sort=downvote

You can see all of the posts you've down-voted. I've noticed a prolific sentiment that folks don't go back and re-visit posts that they've down-voted, to see if they have been improved - and perhaps are worthy of a vote reversal. While the above tab can be helpful in this, if you vote a lot, it is a non-trivial amount of work to click through to each post to see if it has changed. Folks are somewhat unlikely to do this once for any given post, never mind constantly monitor all of their previous votes.

Therefore, I am asking for a visual cue to indicate that a post I've voted on has changed since I cast my vote. This makes it very easy to see, at a glance, if I should go and review any of my votes. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

One idea would be to add a relative timestamp (with an accurate mouseover timestamp, of course) next to any

[image]

Extending this, it would be good to have a sub-tab or some way to filter in order to show *only* those that have changed since I voted.

This feature was discussed a year ago when this tab was first implemented (both in [Pekka's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91449/165455) and [Adam Davis' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91935/165455)), however it never bubbled up to its own top-level feature request (at least not that I could find).

I think this simple addition would make it much more likely that users will feel rewarded for improving a post after being down-voted or closed - right now if they don't get their rep back or get enough reopen votes, they'll wonder why they bothered. And it is far less intrusive than any notification system would be.

Comment: Of course, after I posted, I found [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139270/indicate-revisions-in-vote-history) which is probably similar enough to serve as a duplicate (however I do prefer the explicit timestamp over "3 new revisions" and don't feel that the % edited will always have much relevance).

Comment: I also posted a request fairly similar to this yesterday - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179911/adding-an-edited-section-to-the-votes-tab