# "A [answer|question] you recently down voted has been revised by its author."

Tags: feature-request, voting, edits

I'd like to see a feature where by if I down-vote an answer or a question which is then subsequently improved by its author, that I be notified of this so I may reconsider whether or not my vote remains appropriate.

This increases the 'reward' for posters who correct their mistakes promptly. Restraining it only to recent posts prevents there from being too much noise (since you can only vote 40x in a day, if you kept it to a couple of hours then there'd be a pretty low limit on how bad it could get)

Comment: [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c)

Comment: @Antony, not quite the same - I'm suggesting a passive (and easily ignoreable or even disableable) action rather than a manual request from the OP to 'please look again'

Comment: How do you like [my stars](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157699) ?

Comment: Are you looking for something more passive or less passive than [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180056/add-a-visual-cue-to-votes-cast-tab-to-indicate-modification) or others like it?

Comment: Note we're thinking of one related solution - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow.  Perhaps comments will become "action items" that can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @djechlin but to be relevant here that would require a comment *and* a down-vote. They're not always hand-in-hand - many down-voters don't comment, either because of retribution paranoia or because someone else already made an accurate comment about the problem. I would like to have some easy way to review modifications made to posts I've down-voted regardless of whether I've commented *and* regardless of whether the OP has bothered to click some forthcoming "I've resolved this comment" button.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the question linked because as @PhonicUK said, one request is to allow the downvotee to notify downvoters about an edit, while this one is simply for a passive list that the downvoter can check if they want to in order to revert their downvotes. Voting to reopen (and for the record, I like this proposal better)

Comment: Also, there's already a list of downvotes in your profile (Tab = Votes, Sort = Downvote), so would it really be that hard to just add an "(edited)" suffix to the link if the post was edited after the downvote made? :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not saying what's covered in my link is identical or a complete solution.  But I think it is relevant because outstanding and obsolescent downvotes and comments are related.  Perhaps you'd want to augment the solution so a cleaned-up comment attached to a downvote cleans up the comment as well, or something.

Comment: @Rachel Your suggestion makes sense to me, as long as it also noticed when I last viewed the post, and it might as well be shown for upvotes too.

Comment: FWIW, I just decided to not downvote a question, because I figured I would not remember to check for edits later (and came to meta to see if this has been discussed).