# What to do when downvoters don't leave a comment and an answer is accepted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-answer

I have a very strange situation. I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131101/garbage-collection-best-practice-in-net/19131124) today on Stack Overflow. In the initial stage I got some upvotes, but later on people are downvoting it.

I am not worried about the downvotes, but since my answer was accepted I would like some comments so that I could improve my answer as it is accepted. I can't delete my answer either as it is accepted.

P.S.: I have also tried to edit my answer and improve it after the first downvote!

What do I do in this situation?

Comment: First, do not neck about downvotes in the comments, that's going to do nothing except annoy people. Second, your answer explains close to nothing and jumps between three different topics (what is Dispose(), why GC.Collect() is bad and a note about IDisposable). You should extend it.

Comment: It does seem cruel that an accepted answerer is locked into an accepted answer even if they have come to realise it is bad/wrong

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby:- I will keep that in mind that in future I will not ask the reason for downvotes in comments!

Comment: @RichardTingle of course they are still able to edit/improve the answer if they realize why/how it is bad/wrong.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Assuming they are even able to. I have (on occassion) misunderstood the question, answered what I thought the question was. When I realised the real question I realised I didn't have the knowledge to answer so deleted

Comment: @RichardTingle in those cases all you can really do is comment to the OP that your answer isn't correct, why, and if there's a better answer, point to it. [Example](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49619/wrong-last-modified-date-of-ndf-file-on-sql-server/).

Comment: I dont know if thats going to cost me very bad but I have tried to improve my answer and tried to cover the points. Is that fine or should I ask the community to delete my post. Please forgive me if I am being too excited! Its just that I didnt felt good:(

Answer (score 6):

**In general**

Down-votes are a part of life here. You're never going to be able to explain all of them, and different people may judge an answer on different merits (for example, and I'm not saying it's true in your case, but the asker might find the answer helpful and accept it, even though others see serious problems with it). If you want people to explain their down-vote, it's not going to happen. People who have earned the privilege are free to down-vote as they see fit, and the down-votes are anonymous for a reason. Even if you forced people to leave a comment when they down-vote, that would do two things in a lot of cases, either (1) they would make up gibberish or (2) they simply wouldn't down-vote. We *want* people to down-vote when content is bad, and we're willing to sacrifice the occasional unwarranted down-vote and/or the ability of the poster to understand the down-vote. Please see this thread for more background info on this:

[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Also keep in mind that even if you improve your answer, that doesn't magically mean that down-voters will ever come back and see that, never mind reverse their vote. There currently is no mechanism to notify a down-voter that a post has been improved, though [it has been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180667/a-answerquestion-you-recently-down-voted-has-been-revised-by-its-author) and [more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c).

**In specific**

@MNight makes good points about your answer, and also about posting annoying "explain your down-vote" comments. In fact I've started flagging those as not constructive.

Comment: I highly appreciate your point Sir. I have read this link which you have pasted in the answer. But in my situation the answer was accepted and I didnt wanted the OP to have answer which is downvoted. So what should I do now? Should I as the Community to delete my answer?:(

Comment: @RahulTripathi no, just leave it and/or improve it. It obviously helped the asker, and may help other users too. Who does deleting it help?

Comment: Ok got your point. P.S. Infact after asking the question here got one more downvote for that answer without comments :(

Comment: @Rahul well, for better or worse, if you post a link to a question here on meta, you're going to get all kinds of additional attention on your answer, and their opinions will vary just like its original natural audience did.

Comment: So should I delete the link of the answer from my question here?

Comment: @Rahul no, because then people will harass you for a specific example. I've rolled it back because maybe people here will have some information to help you do exactly what you say you care about: improving the answer.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I think I have done a mistake by asking a question of this type here and doing a bigger one by providing a link as now I am getting some more downvotes!! :(

Comment: Sir I did some changes and tried to cover the OP's question. Is there anything else which I should do or just wait for some upvotes or downvotes P.S. Please forgive me if I am making you feel irritated!

Comment: @Rahul stop worrying about a few down-votes. In the long run they really mean nothing as long as, in general, you're posting good content.

Comment: Thats really motivating words. Thanks a lot Sir!

Answer (score 2):

You don't really answer the question.  You give a bit of an explanation as to what GC.Collect does, and say that it shouldn't be used.  Your post doesn't explain what it means for an object to be disposable, why it's important to dispose resources, why resources need to be disposed in the first place, and how disposing is, in general, different from garbage collection.

Comment: Sir with all my respect I would like to tell you that that was not asked. Although I will try to do the edit but do you think that other answers(Dont take me wrong) are covering that?

Comment: @RahulTripathi The highest voted answer doesn't, the third answer doesn't go into as much detail as I'd like to see, but it's certainly the best there, and is the only one to really answer the question.

Comment: Yes Sir I fully agree and thats what my point is. I accept that my answer is not the best. But it certainly is not the worst to get so many downvotes! :(

Comment: @RahulTripathi Whether a post should be voted up or down is unrelated to the quality of other answers on that post.  Just because there are other bad answers doesn't mean your post shouldn't be downvoted, it means that the other posts should be downvoted as well.  Downvoting your answer, given that it doesn't answer the question and is really lacking in key details, is entirely appropriate.

Comment: Got that! So could you please suggest me what to do now? Should I ask the community to delete my answer?

Comment: @RahulTripathi You can't delete an accepted answer, so it would need to be unaccepted for you to delete it.  The ideal solution would be to actually *fix the post* and edit it to include the information that it's missing and to actually answer the question.

Comment: One last thing Sir should I delete the whole answer then edit the post or should I just write an edit and answer?

Comment: @RahulTripathi As I said, you can't delete an accepted answer, so you don't actually have that option.  Other than that, it's up to you in the general case.  Do you think that what's there adds value even in an incomplete form or not?  For me it depends on how bad the issues with the post are and how much needs to be changed.  For a complete rewrite I generally delete, when I'm just adding more to it, usually not.

Comment: Sir I tried to update my answer and tried to explain what was asked? Do I still miss any point? Please help?