# Indication when other down voters reversed their vote

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes

Like many before me, I've noticed that some questions, which start off bad and take a while to get fixed. Gather a ton of down votes before their state improves and then take ages to get to a positive score. (That is, if they ever do)

A lot has been said [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143262/how-to-keep-track-of-changed-questions-answers-you-already-have-voted-on) [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139270/indicate-revisions-in-vote-history) [topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180056/add-a-visual-cue-to-votes-cast-tab-to-indicate-modification?lq=1) [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179911/adding-an-edited-section-to-the-votes-tab). The interest has been rather large (a total of 88 upvotes on those 4 questions combined), but so far these questions have gathered a staggering total of [exactly one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179911/adding-an-edited-section-to-the-votes-tab/179920#179920) with no less than two up votes. This answer seems to boil down to: it's too difficult and people should use their downvotes more carefully.

Be that as it may, I would like to offer my own suggestion to solve the problem.
Additionally to [indicating revisions in vote history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139270/indicate-revisions-in-vote-history) in a very non intrusive way as [Ben Brocka](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166936/ben-brocka) suggested, I'd like to see a notification that's a little more obvious when someone reversed their down vote on a question you've down voted too. This way, People who are a litte more involved can look at every reviewed question they've down voted and people who are less involved (or just happen to have a little less time at the moment) can still help the question get back on its feet more quickly when it improves its quality.

I see no reason why questions why are perfectly fine should spend time having a negative score just because they were originally bad questions. (I did assume that SE cares more about questions than it does about users) Nor do i see a reason why people who were perfectly righht down voting a question should spend their precious time manually hunting down questions that might have improved since they last saw them.

I'm open to alternative suggestions to solve this problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Whether someone else changed their vote isn't quite relevant in my opinion and really isn't that important to give a notification for. And further, how would the first person know it has changed? You are talking about cascading retracting of downvotes, while it is unsure whether there will be a first one at all.

*At most* I would like a notification if someone changed their post, since that is a better indication something *could* have been fixed. That also opens the way of changing the vote in the first place.

Nevertheless, I don't really see much future for either of those features to be implemented.

Comment: Firstly, reversing a down vote is not possible after a certain amount of time if the post wasn't modified. Secondly, A reversed down vote should be more of an indication than simply any modification since it indicates that a person who (like you) found teh original post to be not good enough has now changed his opinion. Lastly, you can choose to ignore this indication, as I'm not suggesting an actual notification.

Comment: But how would the first person know it has changed? You are talking about cascading retracting of downvotes, while it is unsure whether there will be a first one.

Comment: I did suggest to also implement (more subtle) indications when a post got modified. Additionally, some people may happen to be paying more attention than you are, or just stumble upon the question again by chance (edited posts do get bumped to the top of active questions after all).