# Repeated comments to get your attention

Tags: discussion, comments

Regarding this question, and especially my answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974408/using-images-in-grid-view-view-pager-when-it-is-large-in-size-required-when-i-w/9974453#9974453

The question starter keeps adding comments (and removing them) to get more attention on the answer to this closed question. THe accepted answer has been switched, presumably to get more attention as well from other people?

I have allready asked to stop doing this, but to no avail. I like to folluw up on questions/comments, so I react to the notifications, only to find it being this question again.

What can I do? I figured I could:

- Delete my answer (but I can't, as it is the accepted answer)
- vote to delete the question (but that would be for a wrong reason, so no)
- maybe make the answer community wiki? would that help?

Comment: Flag the post on which the comments are being made, check 'other' and explain to a moderator. They'll look into the behavior and deal with the user if needed.

Comment: I guess that one issue has been a persistent problem for well over a year... (!)

Comment: I have flagged, but that didn't stop anyone. There's no specific need for this user to be banned or anything I think (and the mod probably thought that as well), but I still don't want to be bothered :) ... would community wiki help?

Comment: If this user continues to bother everyone with comments, repeatedly, even when you asked the user to stop, then flagging again is warranted, I'd say.

Comment: I agree, and I have flagged, but I'm looking for a sollution to my (granted, silly) short-term problem of getting the notifications, not necessairily the longterm effects on the user making them :)

Comment: @Nanne: You make it sound as if your question is really a dupe of [More control over multicollider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132922)..

Comment: You can always request a post-lock which will stop him dead in his tracks, at least on your post.

Comment: `"maybe make the answer community wiki?"` - no, that won't help. You still get notifications of comments.

Comment: thanks. postlock request + "cw-wiki does not help" are what I was looking for, :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments:

1. Community wiki will not help for stopping notifications
2. Apart from flagging to get attention to the user, you can ask for "post-lock", so there will be no more comments.