# Can we have settings to control notifications

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

I really don't like that little red box popping up every 10 minutes while trying to make a post on a question or make a question.

Most of the time, the responses aren't really related to me. Some users would like to see the edits, and some don't really care. Some users would like to see the comments on their posts, but some don't want to. Some don't care about their electric bill, some do. It would be helpful if we could block and allow certain notifications on our accounts.

It would further expand the "Edit Profile and Settings" tab and be useful to some people. Default would be allow for all, with like different check boxes for each type of response. For those who don't mind don't need to do anything. Others do and will quickly check off the boxes.

Can we have settings that can allow and block certain notifications?

Comment: Are you actually asking SE to add *more* options?! You've got to be joking... *right*? (jk; +1)

Comment: Yes. Yes I am. :-|)

Comment: "*Most of the times, the responses aren't really related to me*" - how is this so? Do you want to turn them off? Or turn them off when they are not for you? Or turn them off.. what? I don't understand what "options" you want. "*check boxes for each type of response*" - there are only a few response types - comments, edits, answers, etc, surely turning them off means you miss out on important notifications. How will you know if someone has replied to your question or answer if you turn off comment notifications? Just like this comment you are notified of - do you not want to know I commented?

Comment: @James Well what about no notifications for the next timescale?

Comment: Actually http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132922/more-control-over-multicollider is a better duplicate.