# Can I mute notifications on a specific question?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I recently asked my [first question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132272/65907) on Code Golf. In doing so, I was not prepared for the deluge of notifications.

In just one day, I have received over 25 notifications from that single question. Due to the competitive nature of Code Golf, I would prefer to wait and give others more time to answer before looking them over.

**Can an option be provided to unsubscribe or temporarily mute notifications from a specific question?**

Answer (score 8):

This can be difficult (if not concerning) to allow this in actual practice.

One of the purposes of notifications is to uphold *your* end of the implied social contract — that is, if you are asking for help from *others,* it is incumbent upon ***you*** to respond to requests for clarification or improvements on your post.

To allow folks to cut themselves off from that communication channel is akin to saying, *"I just want help, but I don't want to be bothered with the responsibility of upkeep".*

That's the cost of participating in a community crowd-sourced help system.

I can appreciate that there are instance where folks may no longer *need* to follow the tick-by-tick conversations around their post, but if you are going to ask a question, it doesn't sound healthy for a sense of community *self-* moderation to allow folks to say, *"I am no longer listening to this."*

This is not a [status-declined]; just something important to think about.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I acknowledge that Code Golf is a bit of an outlier, and that this request only really makes sense for a select few specific contexts.

Comment: Perhaps some sort of "digest"? Perhaps it would spit out an alert every couple of hours rather than every event?